# How to connect a Gitlab self managed submodule to deepsource.io

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-submodules, deepsource

> I want to connect a git Submodule to deepsource.io. It says I need to connect it via SSH. The main repository is hosted on Github, and the Submodule is hosted by Git lab self-managed (git.server.com).

Where do I have to paste the public SSH key from deepsource.io? Do I have to connect it on my account or the Submodule or how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you generate the SSH keys on deepsource.io (by navigating to a repository's Settings > SSH Access > Generate SSH key pair), copy the public key provided and add it as a deploy key to your GitLab submodule repository (Settings > Repository > Deploy Keys). Do not grant write permissions to the key.

Ref: [How to enable deploy keys on GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_keys/#project-deploy-keys).

If you are using HTTPS URLs to specify submodules (look into the `.gitmodules` file in the root of the repo), they would need to be changed to SSH URLs. To do so, you can

1. directly edit the `.gitmodules` file: If the file looks like this:

```
[submodule "screamer"]
    path = screamer
    url = https://git.myserver.com/org/screamer.git
```

you can change it to look like

```
[submodule "screamer"]
    path = screamer
    url = git@git.myserver.com:org/screamer.git
```

2. Run a command like this:

```
git config --local url.git@git.myserver.com:.insteadOf https://git.myserver.com/
```

This will change your `.git/config` file and look like this:

```
[url "git@git.myserver.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://git.myserver.com/
```

Comment: Thanks I could add this to my submodules. And now it will automatically analyse the submodules after the next push? Or do I have to enable something?

Comment: That depends on whether your submodules are configured as SSH URLs or HTTPS URLs (you can look for them in the `.gitmodules` file). If they look like this `https://git.myserver.com/org/repo`, then they won't work, as your self-hosted git server will then ask for username and password. To fix this, you can configure submodules to use SSH instead: `git@myserver.com:org/repo.git` for example. I have updated the answer to make this point clearer.